# My test Script is to scroll (dynamic) down drop down list till element found in the list and element will get load once the list get scroll down

Tags: robotframework

i am using robot framework. can anyone help me on below code which i have return as its giving error while running script.?

My code is :-

```js
 [Arguments]   ${CustomerName}
    Sleep    4s
    Set Test Variable  ${counter}  24
    log  ${counter}
    FOR  ${counter}  IN RANGE  9999
        log  ${counter}
#        Scroll Element Into View    //div[@tid='customerDropdown_${counter}']
        Execute JavaScript    document.evaluate(\"//div[@class='dropdown-menu w-100 show']/div[${counter}]\",document.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.scrollIntoView(true);
        ${present}=  Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   //div[@title='${CustomerName}']
        log  ${counter}
        Continue For Loop If    ${present} == 'false'  #My Cool Keyword
        Exit For Loop If  ${present}
     END
```

[Arguments]   ${CustomerName}
    Sleep    4s
    Set Test Variable  ${counter}  24
    log  ${counter}
    FOR  ${counter}  IN RANGE  9999
        log  ${counter}

## Scroll Element Into View    //div[@tid='customerDropdown_${counter}']

```
    Execute JavaScript    document.evaluate(\"//div[@class='dropdown-menu w-100 show']/div[${counter}]\",document.body,null,9,null).singleNodeValue.scrollIntoView(true);
    ${present}=  Run Keyword And Return Status    Element Should Be Visible   //div[@title='${CustomerName}']
    log  ${counter}
    Continue For Loop If    ${present} == 'false'  #My Cool Keyword
    Exit For Loop If  ${present}


 END
```

Getting Below error :-

JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of null

Comment: Problem will be with the JavaScript line. Try to get a help from someone who knows JS very well as this doesn't have to do anything with Robot Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `Execute Javascript` line with native SeleniumLibrary keyword: `Scroll Element Into View`
https://robotframework.org/SeleniumLibrary/SeleniumLibrary.html#Scroll%20Element%20Into%20View

Also, real element visibility does not count. I think that the expected condition is checking whether there's any `visibility: hidden` or `display: none` set on the webelement. Easily said, maybe you don't even need to scroll to view the element. :)